# How to find a DLL given a CLSID?

Tags: dll, clsid

I have a situation in which a managed DLL calls some unmanaged DLL.  I know the CLSID of the unmanaged DLL, is there any way to find out what binary file houses that CLSID?

Comment: Are you trying to do this programatically, or ad hoc? I.e., do you need a program to be doing this itself, or is this something you occasionally need to do as a developer?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Normaly, you can just go to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\"GUID"

And find a key called "InProcServer32" for instance and there will be the default value that has the DLL. This is one simple way to do it.

Comment: Worth noting that, depending on how it was installed, you might find it in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID instead.

Comment: Which means that `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID` is what should be used.

Comment: Or HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID

Answer (score 7):

Can you not just search for it in the registry using regedit and look for the binary path.

Answer (score 3):

Based on BobbyShaftoe reply we can build a simple vbs script that reads that registry for us:

```
Dll_RegPath = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<GUID>\InProcServer32\"
```

Paste the following to "test.vbs"

```
Sub Main

    ' used to find location of "System.Collections.ArrayList" progid dll
    Const csGUID = "{6896B49D-7AFB-34DC-934E-5ADD38EEEE39}"

    MsgBox srGetDllPathByGUID(csGUID)

End Sub

Function srGetDllPathByGUID( sGUID )
    Const csRegPath = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<GUID>\InProcServer32\"

    Dim oShell: Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim sReg: sReg = Replace( csRegPath, "<GUID>", sGUID ) ' build str

    srGetDllPathByGUID = oShell.RegRead(sReg)

    Set oShell = Nothing ' clean up
End Function

Call Main
```

You can also find ProgId by:

```
ProgID_RegPath = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<GUID>\ProgID\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this question because I was troubleshooting some incorrectly installed application and my objective was to find and register ActiveX dll given the CLSID (which I've got from app sources). Hence my a little bit hacky approach.

I've issued a search in the directory where I believed the dll is located looking for CLSID in file contents. That did the trick, because it was stored in plain text in resources. I believe it's not always the case, but my problem was solved.