# Finding a dll whose CLSID is known

Tags: dll, tcp

I've downloaded the w3sockets. Primarily using for trying to do telnet via an application. So far we've been experimenting with vbscript. In vbscript we do something like:

```
Set socket = CreateObject("Socket.Tcp")
```

I am trying to use this for a .net application. I need to know the dll it is hosted in. Anyway I can find this?

Comment: Vote to move to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: technically this isn't a programming question

Comment: It sure isn't a sysadmin question.

Comment: It has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897743/how-to-find-a-dll-given-a-clsid

Answer (score 0):

Look in the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and search for Socket.TCP. Drill down and it should be there.

If all there is under there is a guid like

```
{ECCDF543-45CC-11CE-B9BF-0080C87CDBA6}
```

Then search for that under the registry. It should all be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the registry for that progid (the human-readable name), use the entry there to find the classid (the guid for the class) and use the entry there to find the path of the localserver its hosted in... or you could run up [OleView](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open a TCP socket from a .NET application, why are you using an external library instead of System.Net?